# SUM() acting weird when I select from another table

Tags: sql

So when I run the following query:

```
SELECT master.playerID, master.nameFirst, master.nameLast, SUM(managers.G) AS games, SUM(managers.W) AS wins 
FROM master, managers 
WHERE managers.playerID = master.playerID 
  AND managers.playerID = 'lemonbo01' 
GROUP BY managers.playerID;
```

I get the appropriate sum of games and sum of wins. But the moment I include another table, in this instance the pitching table, like this:

```
SELECT master.playerID, master.nameFirst, master.nameLast, SUM(managers.G) AS games, SUM(managers.W) AS wins 
FROM master, managers, pitching 
WHERE managers.playerID = master.playerID 
  AND managers.playerID = 'lemonbo01' 
GROUP BY managers.playerID;
```

Although I'm not changing anything about the query except selecting from one more table the wins and games change to absurd numbers. What is exactly causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY in subqeuries before JOINing.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Your cross join to pitching creates duplicates of your masters/managers. Then you aggregate this intermediate result set and consequently get every sum multiplied by the number of rows in the pitching table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner is there any way to avoid creating these duplicates?

Comment: In your second query, you include pitching, but have no JOIN condition indicating how the master or manager table is related.  So as Thorsten indicated, you have one master, that is being applied to EVERY record in the pitching table.  Is there some game association to link the game played to a pitcher of said game?  That is what is missing.  Edit your question and provide the additional details of the pitching table and I'm sure I (or others) can help resolve your question.